# Using/Creating Python objects with Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

HI,

lets say I have a Java interface B, something like this. B.java :

```
public interface B { String FooBar(String s); }
```

and I want to use it with a Python class D witch inherits B, like this. D.py :

```
class D(B):
    def FooBar(s)
        return s + 'e'
```

So now how do I get an instance of D in java? I'm sorry im asking such a n00b question but the Jython doc sucks / is partially off line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code for your example above. You also need to change the FooBar implementation to take a self argument since it is not a static method.

You need to have jython.jar on the classpath for this example to compile and run.

```
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.PyString;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
public class Main {

    public static B create() 
    {
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.exec("from D import D");
        PyObject DClass = interpreter.get("D");

        PyObject DObject = DClass.__call__();
        return (B)DObject.__tojava__(B.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        B b = create();
        System.out.println(b.FooBar("Wall-"));
    }
}
```

For more info see the chapter on [Jython and Java integration](http://jythonpodcast.hostjava.net/jythonbook/chapter10.html) in the [Jython Book](http://jythonpodcast.hostjava.net/jythonbook/index.html)

Comment: Links seems broken :(

Comment: Up to date link: https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/JythonAndJavaIntegration/#one-to-one-jython-object-factories