# call python modules from java classes?

Tags: java, python, class, module, jython

is it possible, by using jython to call jython classes from java code?

If yes, how please?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582674/using-creating-python-objects-with-jython, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the [Jython FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq) has a [specific entry about this](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/EmbeddingJython).

Comment: beaten by jon skeet...38 seconds faster...:-)

Answer (score 3):

[Nice article regarding this issue](http://tssblog.blogs.techtarget.com/2007/11/21/using-python-within-java/)

Or just try Jython

[Jython Project Page](http://www.jython.org/)